# Apigee push notification - one

Tags: push, apigee

Apigee's push notification is documented here.
http://apigee.com/docs/api-baas/content/introducing-push-notifications

I tried this with the js sdk that Apigee provides here http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/installing-apigee-sdk-javascript. It looks like only the client can generate a notification to itself? [image]

But I have a scenario where I would like to push notifications to multiple clients from a nodejs job that runs once every hour. Something like this, but from the nodejs sdk not from the js sdk.

> var devicePath = "devices;ql=*/notifications";

How do I do this?

Comment: The query statement used within your path can be used to make all sorts of queries for multiple devices - you can adjust that as needed to send one or many notifications.

Comment: I want to do it from a nodejs Backend. Want to send push notifications to the app from the Backend

Comment: You can do that with the [`usergrid`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/usergrid) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As remus points out above, you can do this with the usergrid module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/usergrid).

You are basically trying to construct an API call that looks like this (sending a message by referencing a device):

https://api.usergrid.com/myorg/myapp/devices/deviceUUID/notifications?access_token= access_token_goes_here '{"payloads":{"androidDev":"Hello World!!"}}'

Or like this (sending a message by referencing a user who is connected to a device)
https://api.usergrid.com/myorg/myapp/users/fred/notifications?access_token=access_token_goes_here '{"payloads":{"androidDev":"Hello World!!"}}'

You can do this with code that looks something like this:

```
var options = {
    method:'POST',
    endpoint:'devices/deviceUUID/notifications',
    body:{ 'payloads':{'androidDev':'Hello World!!'} }
};
client.request(options, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        //error - POST failed
    } else {
        //data will contain raw results from API call
        //success - POST worked
    }
});
```

or

```
var options = {
    method:'POST',
    endpoint:'users/fred/notifications',
    body:{ 'payloads':{'androidDev':'Hello World!!'} }
};
client.request(options, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        //error - POST failed
    } else {
        //data will contain raw results from API call
        //success - POST worked
    }
});
```

Note:  the second call, that posts to the users/username/notifications endpoint assumes that you have already made a connection between the user and their device (e.g. POST /users/fred/devices/deviceUUID).